# Enable Disable Watch Target in iPhone app setting Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, watchkit

Recently I have developed the watch app for my iPhone app and added the watch target in iPhone app. 
I want to know is there any kind of setting by which I can choose to add/hide(enable/disable) watch target in iPhone app, like in current market release I don't want to include the watch app, so is there any setting by which I can make it disable in iPhone build but code exist in app.
Is there any kind of target/info plist or build settings by which I can achieve this.

Please suggest.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your application target, Build Phases, Target Dependencies, and remove the WatchKit Extension from the list.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not work, after removing the target, when running  it gives error: **WatchKit Extension.appex: No such file or directory.....

Comment: Also, in extension it needs to be removed, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Build Phases,Copy Bundle Resources in your Target,copy the watchkit app.There need no inclue watchkit app.